# Will the performance of AppendToFile(string,IEnumerable) slow down as the CSV file grows large?

Tags: c#, .net, filehelpers

I am using the AppendToFile method of DelimitedFileEngine from FileHelpers.

Assumptions:

- Each row that I append is about 100 chars long.
- Moderate common PC hardware from the last 3 years, normal harddisk, 4GB ram.
- Frequency of calling AppendToFile is not more than 2 Hz.

How much slower will AppendToFile() get as the plaintext CSV file grows to 10MB, 100MB, 1GB?

If I do not expect it to grow larger than 100 MB, do I need to worry at all about performance?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on loads, loads, loads of implementation details. Slightly relevant: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html

Comment: In theory, append should not depend on size at all. In practice it will vary wildly, but not grow systematically. But do you have alternatives?

Comment: Have you tried it?  What were the results?